# How to pass keyboard accelerators from Axhost to containing .NET form

Tags: c#, winforms, activex, keyboard-shortcuts, axhost

I have an Activex control hosted inside a .NET form using Axhost as a wrapper.
I've defined a shortcut key in the ProcessCmdKey method of the form, but when thye focus is inside the Activex, the keyboard messages and events are captured and not being handled by the ProcessCmdKey.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    AxDirControlLib.AxDirList dirlist = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dirlist = new AxDirControlLib.AxDirList();
        //dirlist.PreviewKeyDown += dirlist_PreviewKeyDown;            

        panel1.SuspendLayout();
        dirlist.BeginInit();
        panel1.Controls.Add(dirlist);
        panel1.ResumeLayout();
        dirlist.EndInit();
    }        

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New project");
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("--------------MainForm---------");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(keyData);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("--------------MainForm---------");
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

I did manage to workaround it by using SendKeys from the PreviewKeyDown event handler of the Axhost, but it's messy and requires some focus shifting for it to work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try also overriding [Control.IsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx) and watch for the keys you're interested to handle. If that doesn't work either, and you have no control over the ActiveX control source code, you could try to handle this situation using WinAPI's [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([KeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). The p/invoke signature is defined [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex).

**[EDITED]** To override `IsInputKey`, you'd need to derive a new class from `AxDirControlLib.AxDirList` and do it in that class. Then add an instance of that class to the form instead of `AxDirControlLib.AxDirList`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, unfortunately I tried overriding IsInputKey and it didn't work, it actually was never called in my scenario... The windows hook solution is not an option in my case (this is just a demo code to simulate my problem)

Comment: Did you try overriding `IsInputKey` on the ActiveX wrapper or on `Form1` (like you do with `ProcessCmdKey`)?